# how to apply different tooltip for every item in a checkbox list in winforms?

Tags: winforms, for-loop, tooltip, checkboxlist

I have tried adding a tooltip for the items in a checkbox list, it applies for the entire checkbox, but I need to apply different tooltip for every item in checkboxlist in winform. I 'm a beginner. Could someone help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would update a Label with the extra information about each entry (changing tooltips dynamically is messy in my opinion).  You can use the MouseMove() event and check to see if the cursor is within the bounds of the rectangle returned by GetItemRectangle():

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.MouseMove
    Dim pt As Point = CheckedListBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
    For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckedListBox1.GetItemRectangle(i).Contains(pt) Then
            Label1.Text = "Info about: " & CheckedListBox1.Items(i).ToString
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```